# SharePoint Server 2016 configuration failed

Tags: sharepoint-2016

Say SORRY at first that I really don't know how to submit feedback to Microsoft.

I had tried every edition of SharePoint and SQL Server. Which the new released SharePoint Server 2016 occur the error below again and again when running Configuration Wizard:
An error occurred while getting information about the user sp_admin at server hub.com: access denied

Other edition likes SharePoint Server 2013 and (SQL Server 2012 SP3 or 2014 SP1) works fine with same configuration.

So two questions,

1. How to do feedback?
2. How to resolved this bug?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are running the setup with the setup user account (spAdmin) and configured its necessary security roles for the sql server:

- securityadmin (fixed server role)
- dbcreator (fixed server role)

See this [reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ee662513(v=office.16).aspx) for details about suggested domain accounts and their security roles.